# find value furthest to the right in a table r

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I've got some data:

```
data <- tibble(A = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
           B = c("e", "f", "g", NA_character_),
           C = c("h", "i", NA_character_, NA_character_))
```

Which looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  A     B     C    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 a     e     h    
2 b     f     i    
3 c     g     NA   
4 d     NA    NA
```

What I'd like to do is get the value that's furthest to the right into a new column:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  A     B     C     D    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     e     h     h    
2 b     f     i     i    
3 c     g     NA    g    
4 d     NA    NA    d
```

I know I could do it with `case_when` and a bunch of logical `!is.na(A) ~ A,` statements, but say I've got a load of columns and that's not feasible. I feel like there probably is an easy way that I just don't know about and haven't been able to find. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coalesce` would be more easier

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    mutate(D = coalesce(C, B, A))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  A     B     C     D    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 a     e     h     h    
#2 b     f     i     i    
#3 c     g     <NA>  g    
#4 d     <NA>  <NA>  d
```

---

Or if there are many column, `rev` the column names, convert to `sym`bols and evaluate (`!!!`)

```
data %>%
     mutate(D = coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(rev(names(.)))))
```